# SBT: modify the order of dependencies in the classpath

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

I'm currently experiencing a problem with Specs2 + SBT where my tests always fail via command-line because of dependency order in the classpath. Specs2 requires that the Mockito jars come after the Specs2 jars so that Mockito classes can be overridden to fix issues with by-name scala method parameters (see this issue for more information: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/428).

In IntelliJ, I can order my dependencies via the `Project Structure/Modules/Dependencies` window, which fixes my tests when run inside IntelliJ, however, I have not found a solution to fix this issue when running my tests on the command-line via `sbt test`.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the classpath order of dependencies for SBT using settings in `build.sbt` (or similar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge you need to make sure that `specs2-mock` comes before `mockito` in your `libraryDependencies` setting.

Comment: Thanks, updating our `build.sbt` to the following seems to fix the issue:


```scala
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.0",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-common" % ProjectSettings.version.specs2,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % ProjectSettings.version.specs2,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % ProjectSettings.version.specs2,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-mock" % ProjectSettings.version.specs2,
```